Amplify Using Incorrect Environment Variables Across Multiple AWS Accounts
I'm facing a strange issue with environment variables.
I have multiple AWS accounts, and I'm using Amplify for Next.js deployments. I've connected the same repository to different AWS accounts through Amplify, with different branches connected to different AWS accounts. The issue I'm facing is that, although I've added different environment variables for each Amplify project, it always seems to use the environment variables from my initial development setup on the first AWS account.
I'm not sure what's going wrong here. I've added environment variable logs in the build process, and I can see the correct environment values in the build logs, but they don't reflect in my app.
